# Drop off Library - Display Forms in a Dialog Disabled now Router Message displays as Dialog Box

Tags: modal-dialog, content-organizer

When using the Content Organizer site feature I have a content type that uses a custom field that doesn't render very well in side the Modal Dialog box.  So I have disabled this function on the Drop Off Library.

When uploading new documents everything works as expected until I finish the submission and the Router Message is displayed.  However when you click the OK button it doesn't do anything.

Looking into this further I can see that the page is passing back isDlg=1 in the QueryString and removing this from the page fixes the problem.  However I can't see a way of telling SharePoint on how to render the page without that QueryString.

Has anyone got any pointers on how the Content Organizer works or a way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The isDlg=1 is what controls whether the resource loads in the full page or in a model window.

From what I'm reading in your note, it sounds like there is something with your custom field type that is interfering with the modal dialog.  What does your field do?  Does it have any special javascript behind it that is perhaps interfering with the standard dialog window and functions?

Comment: Just for clarification the custom field is the reason why I disabled the Dialog.  The behavior of the Drop Off Library with the Dialog disabled is exactly the same with the default out of the box unmodified Document Content Type.

The field itself is all asp.net code and controls, with no JavaScript.